# how do I prevent websites from automatically playing mp3 audio without turning javascript off?

Tags: google-chrome, audio, mp3, javascript

Some websites like http://www.publika.ro/ use javascript to automatically load and play mp3 audio.
How do I prevent any site from automatically starting playback, without losing the ability to run javascript code? (I don't want to turn javascript off)
I am using Google Chrome.

Comment: I sense that this can be possible with this chrome extension, but I can't figure out how to use it to modify content-disposition for audio files so maybe I can force them to be saved instead of opened?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-content-type/jnfofbopfpaoeojgieggflbpcblhfhka?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Comment: Maybe not exactly what you want, but you can make it so you have to click to play any content on a web page. Go to `chrome://settings/content`, scroll down to the **Plugins** section and select **Click to Play**.

Comment: i already have that setting enabled. however the media is played by javascript, not by plugins